# Using SVN in XCode

Tags: svn, xcode

I am sure this is something stupid, but it has me flummoxed.  I have setup SVN to connect to codespaces.com and from the SCM area of xcode, I check it out and it seems to work beautifully.

then I go into xcode and on the status line I get

Error 170001 (Authorization failed) Description: OPTIONS of 'https://alan412@svn.codespaces.com/smilingsoftware/iDirectory/trunk/Directory/Directory.xcodeproj': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (http://svn.codespaces.com)

I have googled this like crazy and all I get are people complaining on mailing lists of similar problems (different providers) and no answers.

Can anyone suggest something to protect what little hair I have remaining???

Thanks in advance,

Alan

Comment: Have you found an answer? (After reinstalling the SDK Xcode forgot my password, reentering it fixed this for me.)

Answer (score 5):

There might be few reasons for this I guess. Although just recently I ran across the same problem myself after upgrade to Xcode 4.
I'm not sure if during the upgrade svn version was updated as well (I see 1.6.5 now). But anyway it was obvious that xcode is not sending correct credentials anymore.

I believe you should try to use svn itself to remedy the situation and "re-cache" the credentials.

Change to your working folder in terminal. Run svn st to see if you have changes. Then use svn commit -m "checkin comment" and if you have the same problem I had, you'll see first auth attempt with your "local" login name. If there is no such account on svn, it will offer you to enter login name and password for svn now.

After that, it started to work in xcode as well.

I published a bit more of [detail on my blog](http://plainoldstan.blogspot.com/2011/03/xcode-4svn-could-not-authenticate-to.html).

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I've got the same error and solved the problem successfully. My SVN server is on the local network, but I think solution will work for codespaces.com either.
[image]

1. First of all, open your repo in XCode, but leave the fields for trunk, branches and tags empty.
   [image]
2. Clean out your repo.
3. Then, create temporary **local** folder with subfolders 'trunk', 'branches' and 'tags' inside.
4. Place all your project files inside 'trunk' folder.
   [image]
5. Go to XCode import all three folders into Root one by one.
   [image]
6. If you did all right, you'll have three folders in root. Go to your repo settings and write the paths for you trunk, branches and tags. I suggest you will write just 'trunk', 'branches' and 'tags'. Indicators must become green.
   [image]

That's all, you can work with you project, check out, commit, make branches etc.